# Google Cloud Video API gives error on using "input_content" argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to use Google Video API and pass a video which is on my local drive using the `"input_content"` argument but I get this error: `` InvalidArgument: 400 Either `input_uri` or `input_content` should be set. ``

Here is the code based on [Google Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/analyze-labels):

```
"""Detect labels given a file path."""
video_client = videointelligence.VideoIntelligenceServiceClient()
features = [videointelligence.Feature.LABEL_DETECTION]

cwd = "E:/Google_Video_API/videos/video.mp4"
with io.open(cwd, "rb") as movie:
    input_content = movie.read()

operation = video_client.annotate_video(
    request={"features": features, "input_content": input_content}
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Video file need to be `Base64` encoded so try this:

```
import base64 
...
operation = video_client.annotate_video(
    request={"features": features, "input_content": base64.b64encode(input_content)}
)
```

Comment: When I use ```base64``` I do not get the mentioned error but when I print the result it says: ```message: "Calculator failed, commonly caused by invalid video, or unsupported format, or file not found, or permission denied."```

Comment: Well, then I leave you the [file](https://github.com/googleapis/python-videointelligence/blob/HEAD/samples/analyze/analyze.py) they use as example. Since all they do is use a single `path` parameter and video in this way `python analyze.py labels f://data/video/video.mp4`, but you need to create a `labels` file